# How to reload only posts in Wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, post, reload

This link is the only solution i found for this problem...
https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/load-posts-ajax/

In my Wordpress theme archives - **header, footer, sidebar are always the same. Only posts are different varying from tags or categories.**

Is there a simpler way to make wordpress load only posts, **for example:**
when you click on navigation (category name), it doesn't refresh the entire page, but **only the post elements**.

I need this function for my archive page, because i'm using archive.php as my base for custom category page design.

ps. I'm a WP beginner :)

Comment: Right after i gave up on my digging, i found this: https://mybrainlounge.wordpress.com/2014/07/13/update-wordpress-posts-without-page-refresh/  but i don't know how to use or understand it... can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use admin-ajax to get the solution .

HTML :

a class="category_nav" data-cat="pass the category value here" href=""

For example , create an function in function.php:

```
function ajax_function() { ?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery(".category_nav").click(function() {
    var cat= jQuery(this).data("category"); // get the category of the post when clicked the navigation

    var data = {
        'action': 'ajax_perform.php',//create a php file to do the wp_query to get the result of passed category value.
        'postcat': cat
    };

    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

    });

    });
});
</script> <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'ajax_function' );
```

Comment: thank you for the comments, i will try this, but unfortunately i can't test it now because i'm due to my deadline and i have to focus on other things... i decided to hardcode this wordpress just so i can pass this milestone... then i'll have time to work on a dynamic solution :/ i will post my result here when i'm done (and i think i can solve it if given time)